# Dose python reportlab has debug log?

Tags: python, linux, centos, reportlab

I get issue about trigger `SimpleDocTemplate.build()` it will hang long time. I check the memory and cpu usage, there is nothing wrong. And I can't reproduce the problem in another server. So i want to get some debug log about reportlab to know the location where cause the long hang time. How can i get the debug log about reportlab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```